# How can I view the logs in an asp.net application using ISS manager?

Tags: c#, server, window

I have a bug that only occurs in production but not development, and I need to see the logs to see what is going on.

I am trying to see the logs in order to fix a bug.

Comment: Have looked in the event viewer logs of the windows server? Maybe the error is shown there.

Comment: The answer to this question is going to depend entirely on how your application logs errors. Do you know what logging framework was used, and how it has been configured?